# Using * and _ to calculate files in directory using $File::Find::dir

Tags: perl, perlscript

Hi I am tring to calculate size of perticular directory using below code but i want to search string as DIR0* to list all directories named DIR01, DIR02. How can i implement this?

```
if ($File::Find::dir =~ m/^(.*)$search/) {
$size += -s ;
}
```

Comment: Please can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? As it stands, this `find` is using a regular expression. (see `perlre`) where you seem to be asking about using a shell `glob` expansion. Translating between the two is actually fairly difficult, so I'd suggest not doing so, and use a regular expression for your search instead.

Comment: `find(sub { if ($File::Find::dir =~ /$ARGV[1]/ ) {`
   `$size += -s ; } `

Comment: I want to calculate the size of files which contain the argument-ed string.  i.e if i give ARG[1] as PRO_A* it have to calculate size of directories which named like PRO_A1, PRO_A2.. etc.,

Comment: Would requiring a regex e.g. `PRO_A.*` be a deal breaker?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**update: 2015-04-27-17:25:24** 
This is how the genereated regex might look

```
$ perl -e"use Text::Glob qw/ glob_to_regex /; print glob_to_regex(qw/ thedir0* /);
(?^:^(?=[^\.])thedir0[^/]*$)
```

And this is how you'd use it in your program

```
use Text::Glob qw/ glob_to_regex /;
my $searchRe = glob_to_regex(qw/ thedir0* /);
...
if( $File::Find::dir =~ m{$searchRe} ){
    $size += -s ;
}
```

**oldanswer:**
use the [rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find::Rule) its got globbing powers courtesy of [Text::Glob#glob_to_regex](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Glob#glob_to_regex)

```
$ touch thedir0 thedir1 thedir5 thedir66

$ findrule . -name thedir*
thedir0
thedir1
thedir5
thedir66

$ findrule . -name thedir0*
thedir0

$ perl -e"use File::Find::Rule qw/ find rule/; print for find( qw/ file name thedir0* in . /); "
thedir0

$ perl -e"use File::Find::Rule qw/ find rule/; my $size= 0; $size += -s $_ for find( qw/ file name thedir0* in . /); print $size "
0
```

and the verbose version that doesn't build a list of filenames in memory

```
use File::Find::Rule qw/ find rule /;
my $size = 0;
rule(
    directory =>
    maxdepth => 1 ,
    name => [ 'thedir0*', ],
    exec => sub {
        ## my( $shortname, $path, $fullname ) = @_;
        $size += -s _; ## or use $_
        return !!0; ## means discard filename
    },
)->in( 'directory' );
```

Comment: `my $searchRe = glob_to_regex(qw/ thedir0* /); `  Not working

Comment: can you be more specific Chetu -- I gave a runnable example using findrule